# Using a new object as a fallthrough versus a constant

Tags: javascript, performance

In many places in my JavaScript (ES6) code, I see the following patterns that check if a key exists on an object and returns an empty object or sometimes array as a way of simulating option fields.

For example

```
const someField = (myObject.wantedKey || {});
// display someField.thing
// or sometimes
const nullIsempty (myObject.undefinedIsEmpty || []);
```

I suspected I could get a relative performance improvement by replacing the new object in the fall-through with a single global empty object like

```
// Defined globally somewhere
const EMPTY_OBJECT = {};

// At the point of use
const someField = (myObject.wantedKey || EMPTY_OBJECT);
```

In theory, I save the overhead of allocating a new object each time this falls through. As long as care is taken to not mutate the object downstream, this works and is confirmed by a simple JavaScript benchmark that shows a notable difference on Firefox 59, Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11. The difference is much smaller on Chrome 65.
[My benchmark](https://jsperf.com/constant-object-vs-new-instance-as-fall-back)

I am right in assuming that the difference in execution speed is caused by reducing how frequently empty objects are allocated in addition to any JIT magic the JavaScript engine does? Is something else happening here?

Clarification: The EMPTY_OBJECT is defined globally in a utility module and imported in as needed. There should only be one instance of the fall-through object when used like this.

Comment: While less object creation a better throughput (less cpu cycles and less memory allocations) you'll gain.  So, you're right!

Comment: Probably, but note that the 10 - 15% you save in this benchmark would likely be much less important in a real application.  "Make it work, make it right, make it fast."  And bother with that last only when necessary.

Comment: btw, you take the same object with a predefined constant ...

Comment: @NinaScholz  He seems to know that, and why he said. -> `As long as care is taken to not mutate the object downstream`

Comment: You could also try putting `Object.freeze(EMPTY_OBJECT)` , as a safeguard against mutating.

Comment: @Keith Good point. I forgot about that.

Comment: While your argument is correct in theory (and sharing would also use less memory), I'm pretty certain that it does not matter in practice. Maybe if you are creating millions of these objects at best, but then you'll have other problems. Btw, [your microbenchmark is meaningless](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).